# Block isn't recognized unless it is defined in the same class

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to define an instance variable which is a block

i have 2 classes as follows

```
@interface ClassA:NSObject

typedef void (^ABlock)(void);
@end


#import "ClassA.h"
@interface ClassB :NSObject

-(void)someMethodWithABlock:(ABlock)block;  
@end
```

in class B the "`ABlock`" type is not recognized unless it is written right above the "`someMethodWithABlock`"

How can I fix it?

Comment: it works for me. your code is valid. you've got an error somewhere else probably

Comment: Are you doing `#import "ClassB.h"` in ClassA.h ?

Comment: i have a global file with all the imports

Answer (score 0):

you want this?

```
typedef void (^blockA)(void);

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassA : NSObject
{
    blockA classAblockA;
}

@end

@interface ClassB : NSObject
{
    blockA classBblockA;
}

@end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you expand your answer a bit? For example, with a description of why this is the right way of expressing it.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

You want to pass a block as an argument of a method

so instead of writing this

```
- (void) someMethodWithABlock:(void (^)(void)) blockA;
```

you want to use typedef to make it more presentable

```
   typedef void (^ABlock)(void);
```

now you can use it as

```
 - (void) someMethodWithABlock:(ABlock) blockA;
```

Now You want to use above typedef to  someWhere else for it you need to import this
.h file where you want to use this typedef(If you are already done it , you must have problem in your  global file where you are importing it).